How to fix VirtualBox making internet connections impossible without uninstalling
Quite a while ago, I installed VirtualBox on my computer so I could test out FreeDOS.
After installing FreeDOS, I couldn't connect to websites such as Youtube, DuckDuckGo, and StackExchange on my host machine.
I uninstalled everything, including FreeDOS and VirtualBox itself. But now, I wish to install VirtualBox again. Anytime I reinstall VirtualBox, I can't connect to most websites anymore. I'm sure it's not a virus.
How can I fix this problem?

What LAN IP address do you use? Does it happen to conflict with the one that "VirtualBox Host Networking Adapter" uses?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

See https://serverfault.com/questions/225155/virtualbox-how-to-set-up-networking-so-both-host-and-guest-can-access-internet to allow both host and VM to connect.

@DrMoishePippik Sorry I took so long to respond. I tried doing that, and it didn't work.
